# Remove workflow hyper link from List View

Tags: list, workflow, hyperlink

I have the following list in a sharepoint 2013 site. I would like to remove the "Approval Problem Status" hyperlink from the list view. In this case is showing as "In Progress" but I only want to maintain the text. This field comes from the default Approval workflow and I'm just showing the status if approved or not.

[image: List View]

I have already tried this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123559/sharepoint-2013-remove-the-hyperlink-from-a-lookup-column-in-a-list-view) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188277/remove-hyperlink-but-keep-text) but with no success. Any other options?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution by using CSR (Client Side Rendering). The javascript was correct but it was not working with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("a[href*='http://myserveraddress/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx']").contents().unwrap();   
  });   
</script>
```

The way it works fine is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
 OnPostRender: function(ctx) {                      
        $("a[href*='http://myserveraddress/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx']").contents().unwrap();       
    }
}); 
</script>
```

And this works for any hyperlink column of the list view including lookups.

Best Regards.

Comment: ``*=`` means containing a string, so you do not need that whole path. nor the ``a`` reference..  ``"[href*='Wrk']"`` is enough. If you only want to hide, a CSS rule ``[href*='Wrk']{display:none}`` is enough

Comment: Thanks Danny, your suggestion works well. Javascript can be reduced

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a calculated field to =[Approval progress status] ?  Then add this to the view and remove the original?

Comment: I cannot use calculated fields since it is a column that is displayed from a workflow status I'm not able to select it in the calculated field options. Adding the Script Editor Webpart and the javascript solved it.